# Endpoints on nested draggable jitter while dragging

Tags: draggable, jsplumb

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jharris/67yupajh/). Click "New Container", drag the container down and right, then click the <kbd>+</kbd> button inside the container. Now drag the new element around. The endpoints attached to it can't decide whether they should be positioned relative to the container or relative to the document, so they jitter back and forth between the two. And this is with `jsPlumb.repaintEverything` being called during the `drag()` function; if you leave that out, the endpoints stay in the wrong location instead of jittering.

I thought perhaps the problem was that containers are [expected](http://www.jsplumb.org/doc/home.html) to have `position: relative`, while draggable items are expected to have `position: absolute`. So I tried putting the interior draggables into a `<div>` with `position: relative` inside the draggable container; that didn't help.

My problem looks like it might be similar to the one referenced in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/issues/231), but that bug supposedly has been fixed. [Another issue](https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/issues/284) mentions that jQuery is unreliable for dragging and we should use vanilla jsPlumb instead; I can rebuild this without jQuery if I absolutely must, but that will make some future plans I have for this project much more difficult.

How can I make endpoint positioning smooth and reliable for nested draggable elements?

Comment: Rewrote this without jQuery; didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different instances: `jsPlumb.getInstance()`. Please play with [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/433tt3uw/). The main problems to be solved in this example are:

1. It's needed to prevent connections between elements from the different instances.
2. It's needed to include resize event handler.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Putting the cells in separate instances is one solution I considered, but I'd like to be able to connect cells in different containers together. :-/